# Improve publishing speed to a target in China

Tags: publishing, scaling, amazon-web-services

We are having a scaled Env with `1 CM and 2 CDs`. CDs are placed in Hong Kong and China and CM in Hong Kong. Each CD has its Web DB hosted in the respective region.

When I publish from CM(hosted in AWS) to `web_CD` in China(hosted in Alibaba), it is very very slow(taking hours to complete a republish site), I think it is because of China Government restrictions. 
How we can improve this.

**Sitecore:** 9.2
Hosted on AWS and Alibaba as IaaS.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your CD server and the corresponding web database is hosted in Alibaba Virtual Private Cloud.

You may want to consider creating a SSL VPN server on your Aliyun VPC and connect your CM server(or publishing service) to it with SSL VPN client, and update host/configs accordingly with private IPs. It may dramatically reduce the latency caused by inbound traffic to China mainland's network.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend investigating the use of publishing service. You need to call your publishing targets properly, along with the search index names postfixing with the name of the publishing targets. Your search indexes should also be as close as possible to the publishing target databases. eg. web-hk, web-cn

However, be ware of some of the potential issues you might face publishing service.  Make sure you test this properly, and be proactive with diagnostic logs.
Please check out my blog post for more info.
https://medium.com/@Vincent_Lui/sitecore-publishing-service-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-74a9c17c9e16

Comment: Thanks for the details, I will check this